# Dynamic SQL If Statement?

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql

I am storing a nested set in mysql.

I use the following dynamic sql to insert a node:

```
    SELECT      @myLeft := lft 
    FROM        t 
    WHERE       id = ?; 

    UPDATE      t 
    SET         rgt = rgt + 2 
    WHERE       rgt > @myLeft; 

    UPDATE      t 
    SET         lft = lft + 2 
    WHERE       lft > @myLeft; 

    INSERT INTO t 
                ( title, lft, rgt ) 
    VALUES      ( "New", @myLeft + 1, @myLeft + 2 );
```

This works fine.  However there is a potential problem, where if the first SELECT does not return any results, the hierarchy will be corrupted.  Wrapping this in a transaction will not prevent this.

How can I ensure the UPDATE and INSERT statements are only executed if the first SELECT statement returns a result?  (If possible, I would really prefer to do this entirely in SQL.)

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `if` (as suggested by Garath) seems like a very reasonable solution to me.  However, if you want to do this within the realm of MySQL SQL, then you can introduce a new variable to count the number of rows returned by the first query.

Then, include this in each of the following `update` and `insert` statements.  To do so, you need to change the last statement from using `values` to using `select`:

```
SELECT      @myLeft := lft , @cnt := @cnt + 1
FROM        t cross join (select @cnt := 0) const
WHERE       id = ?; 

UPDATE      t 
SET         rgt = rgt + 2 
WHERE       rgt > @myLeft and @cnt > 0;

UPDATE      t 
SET         lft = lft + 2 
WHERE       lft > @myLeft and @cnt > 0;

INSERT INTO t 
            ( title, lft, rgt ) 
    select  "New", @myLeft + 1, @myLeft + 2 
    where @cnt > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using IF syntaxt:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

Comment: Does this mean that I have to use a stored procedure?  Is there no way to do it with simple queries?

Answer (score 0):

what about adding `AND @myLeft is NOT NULL` to INSERT & UPDATE statements ?

Example:

```
UPDATE      t 
    SET         rgt = rgt + 2 
    WHERE       rgt > @myLeft
    AND         @myLeft is NOT NULL
```